# Book where sea-level change has caused an apocalypse and people use steamships to scavenge flotsam

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, post-apocalyptic

I remember reading this book in about 2018, but it could be a little older.

The book focused on the crew of a steamship which made their living scavenging flotsam and burning driftwood to keep travelling.

Oil was very limited in this world and the antagonists had an oil-powered ship which was much faster than the heroes' ship.

The only other thing I remember is that Gibraltar was one of the most civilised places, but was also a police state which was known to publicly hang pirates, and also tried to hang our heroes on that charge.